# change tinymce toolbar font family

Tags: css, tinymce

I did integrated `Tinymce` text editor, so I want to change the toolbar `font-family`.

1 is the `font-family` I want to apply. The picture here:

[Tinymce toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aCVt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the theme that comes with TinyMCE and create a custom theme based on it.  The theme includes a variety of CSS so you can change the font-family.

Comment: I did that. here is the css:


`body, table, tr, td, pre, p, ul li, div, i, button{
 font-family:'DroidKufi-Regular';
 font-size:15px;
 }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 font-family:'DroidKufi-Regular';
 }`

and I did link it into tinymce:

content_css: "../../../tinymce/content_mine.css",

Comment: Did you update the CSS files in the theme or did you create a CSS file and use the init to reference it in content_css?  The content_css impacts what is rendered in the TinyMCE wysiwyg view and has no impact on the toolbar etc.